# Reference to Task object isn't pointing to the new Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, stackexchange.redis

I have such method, which read message from Redis and run Task after message was obtained from Redis.

```
private Task _messageSentTask;

private void SubscribeOnMessage()
    {
        _messageSentTask = new Task<bool>(() => true);
        var sub = _redisConnection.GetSubscriber();

        sub.Subscribe(_redisChannel, (channel, msg) =>
        {
            _receivedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMessage>(msg);
            _messageSentTask.Start();
        });
    }
```

At the first run of this method everyting is okay, but I have problem with `_messageSentTask.Start();` when running second time and so on :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Start may not be called on a task that has completed.'
```

I do `_messageSentTask = new Task<bool>(() => true)` before subscribing and starting the Task :

```
sub.Subscribe(_redisChannel, (channel, msg) =>
    {
        _receivedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMessage>(msg);
        _messageSentTask.Start();
    });
```

why `_messageSentTask` isn't pointing to the new Task but remains old completed one ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Task.Run instead of using Task constructor to create new task.

More details on https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html

```
Task.Run<bool>(() =>
        {
            return true;

        });
```